# XML API Request returns "d3p1" for arrays or sub-classes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

Using Postman, C#, .NET Framework 4.7

I make a GET request from Postman with content-accept set to "application/xml" and my .NET Framework Web API will respond with XML (brilliant!).  I have not needed to serialize anything manually as .NET Framework serializes my response object with when I return `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myResponse)`.

However, it seems to include extra things which I am not familiar with and I am wondering if they can be removed via Global.asax settings or similar?

- xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/dto.MyModels" is something I would like to remove!
- "d3p1" is not something I have come across when creating XML. Can I remove it somehow?
- `<error i:nil="true" />` pops up when something is null. Is it possible to just be  or just not appear when it is null?

So, The XML response looks like this:

```
<SimpleResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/dto.MyModels">
    <error i:nil="true" />
    <result>
        <bookList xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/dto.MyModels.Shared">
            <d3p1:Book>
                <d3p1:bookname>Book 1 Name</d3p1:bookname>
                <d3p1:serial>ZMeTaQ1kejh0mJYGHE4+1a4Y2juU6tMDd5zYDqN4tqI=</d3p1:serial>
                <d3p1:id>4</d3p1:id>

            </d3p1:Book>
            <d3p1:Book>
                <d3p1:bookname>Hello World</d3p1:bookname>
                <d3p1:serial>9lM16kho3bgsrG+wRh4ejtZjwrYJwp6FbRqnnZ4CJPA=</d3p1:serial>
                <d3p1:id>5</d3p1:id>
            </d3p1:Book>
            <d3p1:Book>
                <d3p1:bookname>Ding</d3p1:bookname>
                <d3p1:serial>XCqqKB+Wi3i4z6nN1Ry8IHtar6ogojjiqxMfvfgC0qc=</d3p1:serial>
                <d3p1:id>6</d3p1:id>
            </d3p1:Book>
        </bookList>
        <author xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/dto.Models.Android.Shared">
            <d3p1:pictureId>0</d3p1:pictureId>
            <d3p1:websiteurl i:nil="true" />
            <d3p1:email i:nil="true" />
            <d3p1:name>Jo Blogs</d3p1:size>
            <d3p1:age>0</d3p1:size>
        </author>
    </result>
</SimpleResponse>
```

My classes look something like this:

```
public string error { get; set;}
public class SimpleResponse 
{
 public List<Book> bookList { get; set; }
 public Author author { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public string bookname { get; set; }
    public string serial { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public string pictureId{ get; set; }
    public string websiteurl { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The schema is needed to validate the xml.  The validation is finding missing values which is giving the nil = true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/dto.MyModels" is something I would like to remove!***

***"d3p1" is not something I have come across when creating XML. Can I remove it somehow?***

The attributes:

- `xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/dto.MyModels"`
- `xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/dto.MyModels.Shared"`

are both [XML namespace declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1181888/3744182).  The first establishes a default XML namespace for your XML document; the second declares a namespace to which all child elements prefaced with `d3p1:` belong.

From the specific namespace chosen, it's apparent you are using [`DataContractSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer) for XML serialization.  This serializer assigns XML namespaces according to rules documented in *[Data Contract Names: Data Contract Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-names#data-contract-namespaces)*

> By default, any given CLR namespace (in the format Clr.Namespace) is mapped to the namespace http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Clr.Namespace. To override this default, apply the [ContractNamespaceAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.contractnamespaceattribute) attribute to the entire module or assembly. Alternatively, to control the data contract namespace for each type, set the [Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.namespace) property of the [DataContractAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute).

Since you don't want an XML namespace for any of your types, the first option would appear to be the easiest: apply the following attributes to your assembly:

```cs
[assembly: ContractNamespaceAttribute("", ClrNamespace = "dto.MyModels")]
[assembly: ContractNamespaceAttribute("", ClrNamespace = "dto.MyModels.Shared")]
[assembly: ContractNamespaceAttribute("", ClrNamespace = "dto.Models.Android.Shared")]
```

Alternatively, you could apply [data contract attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts) to your types:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Book", Namespace = "")]
public class Book
{
    [DataMember]
    public string bookname { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string serial { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Note that data contract serialization is **[opt-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)** so you will need to apply `[DataMember]` to each member to be serialized.

As a final alternative, you could switch to using [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer) which has no default XML namespace.  To do that you will need to apply [`[XmlSerializerFormat]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.xmlserializerformatattribute) to your service contract as shown in *[Manually Switching to the XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-the-xmlserializer-class#manually-switching-to-the-xmlserializer)*.

***`<error i:nil="true" />` pops up when something is null. Is it possible to just be  or just not appear when it is null?***

These null elements can be removed by setting [`DataMemberAttribute.EmitDefaultValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_Serialization_DataMemberAttribute_EmitDefaultValue) on reference type data members as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/707783/3744182) to *[Can I configure the DataContractSerializer to not create optional (i.e. Nullable<> and List<>) elements in output XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/707711/3744182)* by [Darren Clark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65307/darren-clark):

```
[DataContract(Name = "Book", Namespace = "")]
public class Book
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string bookname { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string serial { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively you could switch to `XmlSerializer` which does not output null reference values by default.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing response.  I have not marked it as answer yet as I need a bit of time to process and also test things out. Much appreciated for your time and effort!

Comment: In order to achieve what I wanted (no namespaces, no d3p1 and no nill values) I added ContractNamespaceAttribute to clear the clrNamespace AND also turned on use xmlSerializer=true in global.asx.  Is that weird and is it bad??

Comment: @PKCS12 - It's not harmful, but once you have switched to using `XmlSerializer`, setting `ContractNamespaceAttribute` becomes unnecessary.

Comment: omg, thank you so much for pointing this out. I just did a full 360. I had the solution to what I wanted all along but had muddled it with data contract serialization :((